# Optimizing table results in "Waiting for table metadata lock"

Tags: mysql, indexing

Running OPTIMIZE TABLE results in "Waiting for table metadata lock". Checking SHOW PROCESSLIST confirms optimizing is the only active query.
I have a table that is 750GB, and 69GB left on the drive. To free up space I decided to cleanup that table. I've turned all access to that server off, and started by deleting old records, which would have ended up taking forever. It has been decided that the table can just be truncated but a small chunk of the data needed to be extracted first. Problem, even a simple SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 1 takes hours before it is manually killed. Is this an indexing issue? And if so is, 69GB enough for the index process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something else you can delete to free up disk space, that *might* release the lock.

Kill the process, make sure there are no tmp tables left around clogging disk.

Then do the cleanup a different way...

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
DROP any indexes you don't immediately need from `new`.
INSERT INTO new
    SELECT ... FROM real
        WHERE ...;
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
If you make it this far, ADD back the indexes you should have.
```

Potential problem:  If the table is Engine=InnoDB *and* was created with `innodb_file_per_table=OFF`, then this is not sufficient to free up any disk space.

If you don't delete more than 90% of the table, and you have only 69GB of free space, the process will eventually fail.

"For the index process" -- This phrase "does not compute".

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` does:

1. Create a new table like the old one, but perhaps without any indexes other than the `PRIMARY KEY`.
2. Copy all the rows (other than deleted ones) over.
3. Build the indexes (assuming they were not incrementally built in step 2).
4. RENAME and DROP (as above)